# Need help preventing infinite loop. Setting of Properties

Tags: c#, wpf, colors

So I have a color picker. Users can pick colors using RGB or HSB. There are sliders/properties for each value. When user sets Red for example, I will calculate HSB values to reflect new color value. When user sets Hue, the RGB value will be recalculated from the HSB values. But see there's a loop there. When I set RGB it must recalculate HSB values, ok so far, but it also means that HSB values will change causing RGB values to be re updated again. I think this is where the problem is but how can I fix this?

## UPDATE: One Possible Solution

One possible solution I used was flag, not very readable tho, but it works. Basically, when I set properties, I also set a flag to signify I am setting a value

```
public float Hue {
    get { return _hue; }
    set
    {
        if (_hue == value)
            return;
        CurrentlySetting = (CurrentlySetting.HasValue) ? CurrentlySetting : ColorType.HSB;
        _hue = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Hue");
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Color");
        RecalculateRGB();
        CurrentlySetting = (CurrentlySetting == ColorType.HSB) ? null : CurrentlySetting;
    }
}
```

When I "Recalculate" Values, I check for that and ensure I am not currently setting them

```
protected void RecalculateRGB(Color color = new Color())
{
    if (CurrentlySetting == ColorType.RGB) // prevent stackoverflow
        return;

    if (color == new Color())
        color = HSBColorHelper.FromAHSB(255, Hue, Saturation, Brightness);
    Red = color.R;
    Green = color.G;
    Blue = color.B;
}
```

Not very straight forward, I still prefer @Marc Gravell's, solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would have all the setters call into the same inner code:

```
public byte R {
    get {return r;}
    set { SetRGB(value, G, B); }
}
public byte G {
    get {return g;}
    set { SetRGB(R, value, B); }
}
```

etc - and that inner `SetRGB` method only talks to the fields (not the properties), including any HSB fields you need; so no recursion. You might also want a `SetHSB`, obviously - again, setting *all* the fields (not calling into any of the property setters).

Comment: I would like to add after setting properties via fields, `NotifyPropertyChanged()` should be run too

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to set a flag to specify wich is the first of the two that changes, then the first thing to do in you function that apply the changes is to control wich one was the first to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I would have the properties be read only and have a method for each of the types. SetRGB and SetHSB